# NextJS build error - ReferenceError: navigator is not defined

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, codemirror

I'm running into this special error message while trying to build a simple NextJS application (using `npm run build`):

```
> Build error occurred
ReferenceError: navigator is not defined
    at /cdk-next/next-frontend/node_modules/codemirror/lib/codemirror.js:18:19
    at /cdk-next/next-frontend/node_modules/codemirror/lib/codemirror.js:11:83
    at Object.<anonymous> (/cdk-next/next-frontend/node_modules/codemirror/lib/codemirror.js:14:2)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/cdk-next/next-frontend/node_modules/easymde/src/js/easymde.js:2:18) {
  type: 'ReferenceError'
}
info  - Collecting page data .
```

I don't know who codemirror is, or why it's not letting me build my project. From reading around I gather that this issue occurs with NextJS when trying to build a project on the server side instead of the client side, because the project does not have access to a window or navigator. In that case, what should I do? The tutorial I'm following seems to breeze through this step just fine, so should I just look at their package.json and downgrade all of my packages? Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Please add some code

Comment: I can give you a repo for the tutorial I'm following, which contains the NextJS code in the ```next-frontend``` folder: https://github.com/dabit3/next.js-cdk-amplify-workshop. My code follows exactly what is in this tutorial. Are there any specific files in my own project that would be useful to show?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error was with my import of `import SimpleMDE from "react-simplemde-editor"` (located in `create-post.js` of the repo link above).

I implemented the solution proposed by modikum here: https://github.com/dabit3/next.js-amplify-workshop/issues/21.

Now the project builds successfully.