# "navigator is not defined" when building Next.js static pages

Tags: next.js, static-site-generation, next.js14

create-issue page in my project.

```tsx
"use client";
import { zodResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/zod";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import * as z from "zod";
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import axios, { AxiosResponse } from "axios";
import {
  Form,
  FormControl,
  FormField,
  FormItem,
  FormLabel,
  FormMessage,
} from "@/components/ui/form";
import { Input } from "@/components/ui/input";
import SimpleMDE from "react-simplemde-editor";
import "easymde/dist/easymde.min.css";
import Error from "next/error";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import React from "react";

const FormSchema = z.object({
  title: z.string().min(2, {
    message: "Title must be at least 2 characters.",
  }),
  description: z.string().min(2, {
    message: "Description must be at least 2 characters.",
  }),
});

export default function CreateIssuePage() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const form = useForm<z.infer<typeof FormSchema>>({
    resolver: zodResolver(FormSchema),
    defaultValues: {
      title: "",
      description: "",
    },
  });

  const onSubmit = async (data: z.infer<typeof FormSchema>) => {
    try {
      await axios
        .post("/api/auth/createIssue", {
          title: data.title,
          description: data.description,
          status: "Open",
        })
        .then((res: AxiosResponse) => console.log(res))
        .catch((err: Error) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
      router.push("/issues");
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center h-[90vh]">
      <h1 className="text-3xl font-bold">Create Issue</h1>
      <Form {...form}>
        <form
          onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
          className="w-2/3 space-y-6"
        >
          <FormField
            control={form.control}
            name="title"
            render={({ field }) => (
              <FormItem>
                <FormLabel>Title</FormLabel>
                <FormControl>
                  <Input placeholder="Title" {...field} />
                </FormControl>
                <FormMessage />
              </FormItem>
            )}
          />
          <FormField
            control={form.control}
            name="description"
            render={({ field }) => (
              <FormItem>
                <FormLabel>Description</FormLabel>
                <FormControl>
                  <SimpleMDE {...field} />
                </FormControl>
                <FormMessage />
              </FormItem>
            )}
          />
          <div className="flex justify-end">
            <Button type="submit">Create An Issue</Button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </Form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The error it shows. Which I cannot figure out. I have read the next.js docs it mentioned but still. It both occurs for my edit-issue page also. What can be the solution for this problem?

> Generating static pages (6/12)  [==  ]  ReferenceError: navigator is
> not defined
> at D:\programs\React\Issue-Tracker\issue-tracker.next\server\chunks\729.js:1:13851
> at 65997 (D:\programs\React\Issue-Tracker\issue-tracker.next\server\chunks\729.js:1:186360)
> at t (D:\programs\React\Issue-Tracker\issue-tracker.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:1:143)
> at 33848 (D:\programs\React\Issue-Tracker\issue-tracker.next\server\chunks\729.js:1:222731)
> at t (D:\programs\React\Issue-Tracker\issue-tracker.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:1:143)
> at 92660 (D:\programs\React\Issue-Tracker\issue-tracker.next\server\chunks\729.js:1:346666)
> at t (D:\programs\React\Issue-Tracker\issue-tracker.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:1:143)
> at 32817 (D:\programs\React\Issue-Tracker\issue-tracker.next\server\app\issues\edit-issue\page.js:1:3126)
> at t (D:\programs\React\Issue-Tracker\issue-tracker.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:1:143)
> at F (D:\programs\React\Issue-Tracker\issue-tracker\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:91937)
> ReferenceError: navigator is not defined
> at D:\programs\React\Issue-Tracker\issue-tracker.next\server\chunks\729.js:1:13851
> at 65997 (D:\programs\React\Issue-Tracker\issue-tracker.next\server\chunks\729.js:1:186360)
> at t (D:\programs\React\Issue-Tracker\issue-tracker.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:1:143)
> at 33848 (D:\programs\React\Issue-Tracker\issue-tracker.next\server\chunks\729.js:1:222731)
> at t (D:\programs\React\Issue-Tracker\issue-tracker.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:1:143)
> at 92660 (D:\programs\React\Issue-Tracker\issue-tracker.next\server\chunks\729.js:1:346666)
> at t (D:\programs\React\Issue-Tracker\issue-tracker.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:1:143)
> at 37911 (D:\programs\React\Issue-Tracker\issue-tracker.next\server\app\issues\create-issue\page.js:1:2578)
> at t (D:\programs\React\Issue-Tracker\issue-tracker.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:1:143)
> at F (D:\programs\React\Issue-Tracker\issue-tracker\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:91937)
>
> Error occurred prerendering page "/issues/edit-issue". Read more:
> https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error ReferenceError:
> navigator is not defined
> at D:\programs\React\Issue-Tracker\issue-tracker.next\server\chunks\729.js:1:13851
> at 65997 (D:\programs\React\Issue-Tracker\issue-tracker.next\server\chunks\729.js:1:186360)
> at t (D:\programs\React\Issue-Tracker\issue-tracker.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:1:143)
> at 33848 (D:\programs\React\Issue-Tracker\issue-tracker.next\server\chunks\729.js:1:222731)
> at t (D:\programs\React\Issue-Tracker\issue-tracker.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:1:143)
> at 92660 (D:\programs\React\Issue-Tracker\issue-tracker.next\server\chunks\729.js:1:346666)
> at t (D:\programs\React\Issue-Tracker\issue-tracker.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:1:143)
> at 32817 (D:\programs\React\Issue-Tracker\issue-tracker.next\server\app\issues\edit-issue\page.js:1:3126)
> at t (D:\programs\React\Issue-Tracker\issue-tracker.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:1:143)
> at F (D:\programs\React\Issue-Tracker\issue-tracker\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:91937)
>
> Error occurred prerendering page "/issues/create-issue". Read more:
> https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error ReferenceError:
> navigator is not defined
> at D:\programs\React\Issue-Tracker\issue-tracker.next\server\chunks\729.js:1:13851
> at 65997 (D:\programs\React\Issue-Tracker\issue-tracker.next\server\chunks\729.js:1:186360)
> at t (D:\programs\React\Issue-Tracker\issue-tracker.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:1:143)
> at 33848 (D:\programs\React\Issue-Tracker\issue-tracker.next\server\chunks\729.js:1:222731)
> at t (D:\programs\React\Issue-Tracker\issue-tracker.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:1:143)
> at 92660 (D:\programs\React\Issue-Tracker\issue-tracker.next\server\chunks\729.js:1:346666)
> at t (D:\programs\React\Issue-Tracker\issue-tracker.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:1:143)
> at 37911 (D:\programs\React\Issue-Tracker\issue-tracker.next\server\app\issues\create-issue\page.js:1:2578)
> at t (D:\programs\React\Issue-Tracker\issue-tracker.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:1:143)
> ✓ Generating static pages (12/12)
>
> > Export encountered errors on following paths:
> > /issues/create-issue/page: /issues/create-issue
> > /issues/edit-issue/page: /issues/edit-issue

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NextJS build error - ReferenceError: navigator is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70992277/nextjs-build-error-referenceerror-navigator-is-not-defined)

Comment: Thanks a lot. That worked out. I used it before in the next.js@13.4 version it was showing error. Now it works fine.